# Highlighting the current page in rails, only works for some pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css

I've used [this](http://24ways.org/2005/auto-selecting-navigation) tutorial to highlight the current page in the menu. I have a pages controller with a few static pages, for the home page I simply have
`def home
  @title = 'Home'` 
and similar for contact pages etc.
Then in my main layout file I have `<body class="<%= @title %>">`
and this works fine to set the correct css, but how do I set @title for my other controllers where there's more than one action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `before_filter` on a controller

```
class Home < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :highlight
  def index
  #...
  end

private
  def highlight
    @title = "Home"
  end
end
```

Comment: that just gives me an error  "uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback::Blog"